# Running Tor on usb flash drive

Tags: flash

I have downloaded Tor and put it on a usb flash drive. How do I run it without putting it in the apps folder on the computer?

Comment: Is your question answered? If not, edit and provide more detail. If so, mark the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You unpack the bundle to your memory stick, and run the 'start tor browser' shortcut.

The bundle is 'portable' and should run from any directory as long as you have the proper access rights to it.